# How to retrieve only 40-50 email like Gmail using Javamail?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to retrieve my inbox using javamail and I have done that but now problem arises when I try to load the code it take lot of time in reading all emails as it read the whole inbox but I want that only few emails should be fetched that are most recent.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
String host = "pop.gmail.com";// change accordingly
properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
//create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");

store.connect(host, username, password);

//create the folder object and open it
Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

// retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
LOG.info("messages.length---" + messages.length);

for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    Message message = messages[i];
    leadJSONObject = new JSONObject();
    LOG.info("Email Number " + (i + 1));
    LOG.info("This log is executed successfully");
    leadJSONObject.put("emailFrom", message.getFrom()[0].toString());
    leadJSONObject.put("emailSubject", message.getSubject());
    leadJSONObject.put("emailText", message.getContent().toString());
    planJSONArray.put(leadJSONObject);
}

//close the store and folder objects
emailFolder.close(false);
store.close();
```

Please Help how can I read only few emails. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to count the messages, then retrieve only a part of the total , e.g for the 50 first messages (or less if there isn't enough):

```
int total = emailFolder.getMessageCount();

Message[] messages =  emailFolder.getMessages(1,Math.min(total,50));
```

cf. the javadoc of [javax.mail.Folder](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/Folder.html).

Comment: Now I want to show the date when it was recieved and I am using message.getSent() and it come in this format Mon May 23 03:11:00 IST 2016 and when I am trying to parse it to Date format dd/mm/yyyy Nothinfg is happen. Please help.................

Comment: Different question .... but `Message::getSentDate` returns a `Date` object, so you should not have to parse it.